# Random path through a rectangle

Tags: matlab, loops, random, path, while-loop

I want to write a code to generate a random path trough a rectangle of a given size.

I will start from the point `(0,0)` and go `up` or `right` to reach `xlim` and `ylim`.

Here is my code,

```
y = 10;
x = 10;
yOld = 0;
xOld = 0;
figure
axis([0 x 0 y])
while yOld < y && xOld < x
    DirectionChange = randi([0 1],1);
    if DirectionChange == 0
        yNew = yOld + 1;
        xNew = xOld;
    else
        xNew = xOld + 1;
        yNew = yOld;
    end
    line ([xOld xNew],[yOld yNew],'LineWidth',3);hold on
    yOld = yNew;
    xOld = xNew;
end
line ([xNew x],[yNew y],'LineWidth',3);hold off
```

The code has a `while loop`, and it ends when one of `x` or `y` reaches it's limit.

So It works fine provided `x = y`.

However, when `y > x` it's more probable that the path reaches `xlim` sooner.

for 12 runs of `x = 10, y = 10`I get (I made it colorful to look better!),

[image]

Setting `x = 10, y = 20`, I get,

[image]

As you can see I lose the randomness in latter case, as the probability of `x` reaching it's limit increases.

Any suggestions how to preserve randomness in case of `x~=y`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need to make x steps to the right, and y steps up. So make an array containing those steps as encoded instructions (a simple array will do just fine here, we can use 0 for horizontal step and 1 for vertical). Then shuffle the array. This is guaranteed to hit the corner without any adjustments, and also all possible paths will be equally likely (as random as you can get).

```
x = 10;
y = 20;
steps = [ zeros(1,x) ones(1,y) ];
steps = steps( randperm(x+y) );

figure
hold on;

xOld = 0;
yOld = 0;
axis([0 x 0 y])
for step = steps,
    if (step == 1)
        yNew = yOld + 1;
        xNew = xOld;
    else
        xNew = xOld + 1;
        yNew = yOld;
    end
    line ([xOld xNew],[yOld yNew],'LineWidth',3);
    yOld = yNew;
    xOld = xNew;
end
line ([xNew x],[yNew y],'LineWidth',3);
hold off
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is make it so that `P(x increases) = x/(x+y)` and `P(y increases) = y/(x+y)`. In this way, the probability that `x` reaches its limit is the same as the probability of `y` reaching its limit.

**Example:** For a given `xlim` of 5 and a given `ylim` of 10, generate a random number from the continuous interval `[0,1]`. If this random number is less than .333, which is `xlim/(xlim+ylim)`, you should increase `xOld`. Otherwise, increase `yOld`.

Use `rand` rather than `randi`.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote on the other solution. I think the issue could be if y is a not a multiple of x when y > x or x not being a multiple of y when x > y, otherwise it looks fine to me. What do you think?

Comment: @Divakar Your solution looks fine as long as OP is okay with handling non-integer movement. The differences between the two solutions (Arpi's/mine and yours) are that we change the *probability* of movement and you change the movement *amount* to keep the probability of hitting either limit the same. Two different and valid solutions to the same question.

Comment: Alright sounds like a relief to me that it looks valid in some way. So, what about the downvote, was it for some other reason? Sorry to bother, if it wasn't you.

Comment: That was a good lie though!:) But it's okay, probably wasn't the best of answers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to condition the direction choice on the ratio of dimensions, e.g.

```
DirectionChange = rand(1);

if DirectionChange < y/(x+y)
    yNew = yOld + 1;
    xNew = xOld;
 else
    xNew = xOld + 1;
    yNew = yOld;
 end
```

[image]

Are there any requirements which should be kept? e.g. constant step size

**EDIT:**
More effective strategy to avoid hitting the 'walls':

```
DirectionChange = rand(1);

% distance left to the end
xLeft = x - xOld;
yLeft = y - yOld;

if DirectionChange < yLeft/(xLeft+yLeft)
    yNew = yOld + 1;
    xNew = xOld;
else
    xNew = xOld + 1;
    yNew = yOld;
end
```

Comment: Your edit doesn't preserve randomness--it makes you less likely to move in one direction given a position that is not on the diagonal between the top right and bottom left corner. It is possible that OP would like this behavior, but I want to make sure to point out that the method you (and I) used initially  *correctly* scales to a case where `x<>y`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am aware of that, but the OP did not specify the requirements. I think that my edit still preserves randomness, but in a non-stationary way.